# How do I log out of `sudo su`?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I'm using `sudo su` to start `mysql` and do some homework with it.

When I finish with `mysql` (or any other command), then I'm still in `sudo`.

How do I "log out", so my prompt changes back from `#` to `$`?

Comment: Use exit command ..

Comment: `exit` or a simple Ctrl+D. I remember when I first discovered the latter and my life got ten times simpler :-D .

Comment: Apart from the good answers below there remains one point: **if** you need a shell with *root* permissions on Ubuntu you type `sudo -i` (and leave it with CTRL+D)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You don't need to use `sudo` and `su` together--`su` switches your user account (without arguments it switches you to root). `sudo` just elevates your privileges to root for the current command.

It's reccomended to use `sudo` instead of `su` if possible, but to return to your normal account after calling `su`, simply use the `exit` command

Comment: `sudo su` will switch to the root account even if you don't know the root password.

Comment: There *are* differences between `sudo su`, `sudo` and `su`, and it's worth knowing those differences for safety reasons but also for your convenience.  http://johnkpaul.tumblr.com/post/19841381351/su-vs-sudo-su-vs-sudo-u-i

Comment: @Rob but still it may not set the environment in a desired way - use `sudo -i` instead (in Ubuntu the *root* account is disabled by default = there exists no valid password)

Comment: @Rob or `sudo -s` for **s**hell.

Comment: Nothing suggested here works

Comment: If you type su multiple times, you get into a nested su. You also need to exit multiple times then.

Answer (score 40):

Use

```
su username
```

to get back to your user level (or a different user)

Or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to exit out of root

Comment: you don't want to su deeper... Ctrl-D or exist or logout are all good choices

Comment: @Ram - you made an important point. But there's a typo in your comment. It should be `exit` (not exist).

Comment: typo indeed @MountainX ... CTRL-D, exit, logout etc.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works.

Comment: @Totty.js Then you're using `su` wrong.

Answer (score 10):

- `logout` if used `sudo su -`
- `exit` if used `sudo -s`

Answer (score 2):

if your stuck after using **sudo su** as root: to exit use this command

```
su -l <user_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any reason to use `sudo` or `su` to run the MySQL command-line client. It defaults to using your current Unix user as your MySQL user, but instead you should pass it the user you want to connect to as arguments:

```
$ mysql -u root # connect as MySQL's root user (without password)
$ mysql -u root -p # -p means prompt for a password
```

Hopefully, your MySQL root account has a password, and you'll need to use the second form.

Other than that, if you need to run MySQL under sudo (e.g., for file permissions) then do it like this:

```
$ sudo -u unix-user mysql -u mysql-user -p
```

You can leave out the arguments (sudo will default to user root, MySQL will default to using the same user as sudo).

Answer (score 0):

if you get access denied message -for example - while login to mysql with root password like:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

try:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

for one time elevation of privileges, for multiple commands use:

```
sudo su
```

you will notice that your terminal changed to **[root@yourpc]#** then whatever commands you like to run
when you want to return back to your own user hit **ctrl + d** , type **exit** or

```
su username
```

your terminal will be back to **[username@yourpc]#** and you are now using you own user permissions